# Google Analytics on Ebay using owned server

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, customization

I have an ebay store and I would like to use Google analytics to track everything. I have also a web site that could act as bridge between the two services since I'm aware that ebay does not allow the use of any kind of javascript.
Could be enough to place an image on my website, track it with analytics, and link the image from the ebay auction page? Or do you have a better solution? 
I don't want to use third party paid services since they are overkill for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could include a reference to the google tracked image on the site (see http://code.google.com/p/google-analytics-js/) but unless you can customize the parameters on the image request you will lose some of the Analytics functionality.

if you do have a second server then you could add a reference on your eBay site to a remote hosted piece of javascript via the img src - the javascript could then function as in the analytics sample above and return a single pixel image to your eBay page

It's not going to be a complete solution as, without JS in the page, some of the analytics functionality won't be able to provide data back to the service but (provided eBays "sanitization") allows the js source  on an image tag you would at least get concurrent users, and location etc

Answer (score 0):

If you're running PHP on your own server you could use a PHP hack. Have a PHP script that sets headers to image type: `header('Content-type:image/png');`. That PHP script will serve an image which can be used in an img tag, but you can also use PHP to process some simple access analytics. Your img will look like this:

`<img src='http://www.yoursite.com/trickyimage.php' />`